# Go grpc server constrain worker

Tags: go, concurrency

Go newbie here, I know by default go lunches a go routine to handle every incoming request, Is there a way I can control the number of go routines that handle the requests in a grpc server by having a worker pool? for example I want to only have 20 GRs to handle the requests, regardless of the number of incoming requests.

```
type server struct{}

func (s *server) HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, in *pb.IncomingRequest) (*pb.Server.Response, error) {
    //Do Something
    return &pb.Server.Response{Message: "received request"}, nil
}

func main() {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }
    s := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterMyServer(s, &server{})
    log.Printf("Server listening at %v", lis.Addr())
    if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this? Goroutine creation is not an expensive operation like thread creation. If you need this for throttling, there are simple ways to reject concurrent requests above a certain number, like keeping an atomic counter or a channel with a given capacity and reject requests beyond a certain number.

Comment: I need it for a specific test, how can I use channels to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of worker pool pattern in golang. You should define your Job in this pattern.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func worker(id int, jobs <-chan int, results chan<- int) {
    for j := range jobs {
        fmt.Println("worker", id, "started  job", j)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        fmt.Println("worker", id, "finished job", j)
        results <- j * 2
    }
}

func main() {

    const numJobs = 5
    jobs := make(chan int, numJobs)
    results := make(chan int, numJobs)

    for w := 1; w <= 3; w++ {
        go worker(w, jobs, results)
    }

    for j := 1; j <= numJobs; j++ {
        jobs <- j
    }
    close(jobs)

    for a := 1; a <= numJobs; a++ {
        <-results
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Worker pools are best suited for tasks that require expensive initialization so that creating goroutines as needed would not be preferable.

There are ways to limit the number of concurrent calls using channels. The following will immediately return when there are too many calls:

```
var limiter = make(chan struct{},limit)

func (s *server) HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, in *pb.IncomingRequest) (*pb.Server.Response, error) {
  select {
    case limiter<-struct{}{}:
      defer func() {
         <-limiter
      }()
    default:
      return nil,TooManyCalls
  }
  // Body
}
```

Another version will queue up all requests, and process them with at most `limit` concurrently:

```
func (s *server) HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, in *pb.IncomingRequest) (*pb.Server.Response, error) {
  limiter<-struct{}{}:
  defer func() {
      <-limiter
  }()
  // Body
}
```